# Error with NPM install - code ENOTFOUND

Tags: npm, installation

I am trying to run 'npm install' for my homework assignment - which has the package.json file given to me already but I keep on getting the following error:

```
Ramons-MacBook-Pro-3:project4 sacrams14$ npm install
npm WARN package.json project4@1.0.0 No repository field.
npm WARN package.json project4@1.0.0 No README data
npm ERR! Darwin 14.0.0
npm ERR! argv "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install"
npm ERR! node v4.2.6
npm ERR! npm  v2.14.12
npm ERR! code ENOTFOUND
npm ERR! errno ENOTFOUND
npm ERR! syscall getaddrinfo

npm ERR! network getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND registry.npmjs.org registry.npmjs.org:80
npm ERR! network This is most likely not a problem with npm itself
npm ERR! network and is related to network connectivity.
npm ERR! network In most cases you are behind a proxy or have bad network settings.
npm ERR! network 
npm ERR! network If you are behind a proxy, please make sure that the
npm ERR! network 'proxy' config is set properly.  See: 'npm help config'

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /Users/sacrams14/Dropbox/CS 142/project4/npm-debug.log
```

Answer (score 0):

It really seems that there is problem with your internet connection.

1. Please check internet connectivity (seems to work beacause you were able to write here ;)).
2. Check current version of `npm` and your installed version. Maybe old version is not able to contact with server.
3. Check out if your firewall allows `npm` to contact with the internet.